How to control version of setuptools used to build dependencies?
Description of problem:
We have a project with the following dependencies:
requirements = [
    'setuptools'==40.4.3,
    'package_a'==2.2.1
]

We use a custom pip index specified by a remote url. In this url, we have many versions of setuptools, some of which are higher than the one specified.
When pip goes to find package_a, it finds it as a tar.gz. When it goes to build it, it starts looking for setuptools and finds the latest version specified in our repo, NOT the one that is already installed (40.4.3). The newer version it finds is incompatible with our version of python.
How do we get pip to recognize the already installed setuptools dependency when building other packages?

requirements = […] is run-time requirements. Put build-time requirements in pyproject.toml: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyproject.toml%5D+setuptools+version , https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/ , https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html
